# How to use downloadr with ruby-progressbar?

Tags: ruby, download, progress-bar, mechanize

What I want to do basically is download a file over HTTP while showing progress and ETA .. I managed to find a way to achieve that using open-uri + [progressbar](https://rubygems.org/gems/progressbar), but I want to know if I can do the same with **[downloadr](https://rubygems.org/gems/downloadr)** (or **mechanize**).

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'progressbar'
require 'downloadr'

file     = 'URL/XXX-YYY-123.zip'
filename = 'x.zip'
filesize = Mechanize.new.head(file)['content-length'].to_i

pbar = ProgressBar.create(title: filename, format: "Downloading [ %t ] ~ [%b%i] [%P%% ] [%E ]", total: filesize, progress_mark: '=')
pbar.progress = amount_downloaded
Downloadr::HTTP.download(file, filename)
```

The concept is to get filesize and set it as "total" in `pbar`, and then increment `pbar.progress` by the amount we've downloaded.

Comment: maybe one of these answers can be adapted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301009/get-file-size-before-downloading-counting-how-much-already-downloaded-httpru

Comment: Can't find a way to figure out how much data has already been downloaded  ..